# Garantir ordenação aleatória de resultado de query

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho a query abaixo, que utilizo para verificar ip's validos de coletores na rede para distribuição de itens para separação:

```
Select distinct IP, USUARIO, trunc(DATA)
from
PCN_ROMANEIO_ACESSO    PRA
Where pra.STATUS = 'OK'
AND trunc(pra.DATA) = trunc(sysdate)
AND PRA.DATA_SAIDA IS NULL
AND IP <> '192.168.204.1'
AND NIVEL = 'S'
order by dbms_random.value
```

Com o `dbms_random.value` ele eventualmente troca a posição dos resultados da query, mas na maioria das vezes ele mantém as mesmas posições da execução anterior, conforme exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma forma, somente com Oracle SQL, de "garantir" que as posições sejam todas trocadas a cada execução da query?

Comment: Eu não sei muito sobre Oracle. Mas não é possível isso : order by dbms_random.value,rand() ? Se eu não me engano essa função internamente usa o timestamp para ordenar aleatoriamente, portanto garantiria o resultado diferente.

Comment: @RafaelSalomão existe o dbms_random.random, coloquei os dois mas ainda sim fica o mesmo resultado em até 3 execuções....

Answer (score 1):

Tem quantas ocorrências na tabela ?

Já fiz um relatório semelhante e este problema não ocorreu mas existe milhares de dados na tabela, com poucos casos a chance de sortear os mesmos é alta.

Em todo caso tente assim :

```
select IP, USUARIO, data
from  (
Select distinct IP, USUARIO, trunc(DATA) data
from
PCN_ROMANEIO_ACESSO    PRA
Where pra.STATUS = 'OK'
AND trunc(pra.DATA) = trunc(sysdate)
AND PRA.DATA_SAIDA IS NULL
AND IP <> '192.168.204.1'
AND NIVEL = 'S'
)
order by dbms_random.value
```

Answer (score 1):

Só tens 3 colunas para ordenar. Tentar forçar os limites do random para gerar um numero entre 1 e 3

```
dbms_random.value(1,3)
```

Claro que sendo apenas 3 hipóteses, é bastante provável sairem algumas execuções com ordernação repetida.